# How to Disable Mouse Wheel Event in AVPlayerView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouse, mousewheel, avplayerview

While AVPlayerView Watching,
Sliding Mouse Wheel makes pause movie then fast forward or rewind.
this makes process error.

I set AVPlayerView Mode as NONE, btw.

let me know how to disable mouse wheel event on AVPlayerView.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 (forwards scrolling to the view underneath it):

```
class NonScrollableAVPlayerView : AVPlayerView
{
    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent)
    {
        if self.superview != nil
        {
            self.nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the `superview` check necessary?

Comment: This doesn't prevent trackpad swipe gestures from scrubbing the video player

Answer (score 0):

Override hitTest:

```
@interface MyAVPlayerView : AVPlayerView
@end

@implementation MyAVPlayerView

- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
   if (prohibitScrolling) {
      return nil;
   } else {
      return [super hitTest:aPoint];
   }
}

@end
```